# Setting an initial value outside and inside loop

Tags: java, loops

I was wondering what would be a real difference between setting up code like this

```
public boolean stringE(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i =0; i < str.length(); i++) {     
     if (str.charAt(i) == 'e') {
         count += 1;
     }
  }
  return (count >=1 && count<=3 );
}
```

and this

```
public boolean stringE(String str) {
  for (int i =0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int count = 0;     
    if (str.charAt(i) == 'e') {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return (count >=1 && count<=3 );
}
```

I know the first one is right but what would make it difference by setting "int count =0" inside "for loop". Wouldn't it still add 1 to the count =0 ?

Comment: Yes, but the scope of "count" in the second example would be restricted to the for loop. If you closed the curly braces properly you would probably see that :)

Answer (score 5):

The second case won't compile, since `count` won't be recognized in the `return` statement, since the scope of the `count` variable is only inside the `for` loop in that case.

That's why you have to declare `count` outside the `for` loop.

Another problem with the second case, as mentioned by Dici, is that you reset `count` to `0` in each iteration of the loop, which means the loop wouldn't count what it is supposed to count.

Comment: You should still mention that count is reinitialized each turn of the loop. His example is not good but you should provide an example outside of a method and explain why it is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In second case, the variable count is not visible outside for loop so that will create error at return statement. Also the logic is wrong since it will get reset everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try - and in this case, you might notice that the second one won't compile. It's syntactically incorrect.

In Java, when you define a variable, it only exists in the scope of the braces `{}` it's defined in. If you define a variable inside a loop, it only exists inside the loop. You can't use `count` outside the braces it's defined in.

Also, I doubt even the first program is semantically correct - you always `return` during the first iteration, which is unlikely to be what you want.